# Compiler modifying a variable without adressing it

Tags: c#, variables, dictionary

In my program I found that when asssigning a variable to another, modifying the first one, also modifies the second.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Dict_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> Dict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            Dict1.Add("one", 1);
            Dict1.Add("two", 2);

            Dictionary<string, int> Dict2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            Dict2 = Dict1;

            Dict1.Remove("two");

            MessageBox.Show(Dict2["two"].ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make sure that Dict2 doesn't change when changing Dict1.
If possible without `const Dict2`
I come from a python environement and find this very disturbing
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are currently doing:

```
Dict2 = Dict1;
```

Is reference copying, so both `Dict1` and `Dict2` are pointing to the same location. You can create a new copy like:

```
Dict2 = Dict1.ToDictionary(d=> d.Key, d=> d.Value);
```

*Remember*, if your `Key` and `Value` are custom objects (based on some class), in that case your second dictionary will have references for the same objects as first dictionary. See [How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)